# How to synchronize cell values in the same table?

Tags: php, mysql, database-deadlocks, optimistic-concurrency, database-concurrency

Big problem...

I'm implementing an online ticket sale system in PHP and MySQL. I have a table called "block_of_tickets", or something like that...

This table looks like:

```
+-----------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| idblock   | block_name | total_tickets| block_gender | idblock_pair |
+-----------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|     1     | Block 1- M |     100      |     MALE     |      2       |
+-----------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
|     2     | Block 1- F |     100      |    FEMALE    |      1       |
+-----------+------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Where:

1. **idblock:** The id (primary key) of the block of tickets.
2. **block_name:** The name of the block. In the example I have a "Block 1- M" and "Block 1- F" to represent the "Block 1 - Male" and "Block 1 - Female", respectively.
3. **total_tickets:** the total of available tickets
4. **block_gender:** the gender of the block of tickets
5. **idblock_pair:** the block which is pair of the current block.

**Note: There are also other columns, like "price", etc.**

Here is the (big) problem:

1. When there is a "**idblock_pair**", it means that both block of tickets will share the same total_tickets (available tickets), so both cells must have exactly the same value in this case. As you can see in the example above, **block 1 points to block 2 and vice-versa**.
2. Lots of people buy lots of tickets in (almost) the same time, which means that each sold ticket must decrement 1 in the "total_tickets" field, for both cells.

Database Normalization can solve this. However, it would lose a lot in performance.

I'm almost sure that I should use "SELECT... FOR UPDATE"... but I don't know how, since it's the same table, and a "deadlock" can occur...

How to solve this problem? Do I have to use Triggers? Procedures? Do I have to use the PHP processing (and transactions) to solve this?

---

In the example below, one ticket were sold, and now I'm decrementing the **total_tickets** by 1:

```
START TRANSACTION;

SELECT * 
FROM block_of_tickets
WHERE idblock in (1,2) FOR UPDATE;


UPDATE block_of_tickets
SET total_tickets = (total_tickets - 1)
WHERE idblock in (1,2);

COMMIT;
```

Is this a nice solution?

Comment: If I understand, then why not the simple update `UPDATE block_of_tickets SET  total_tickets = total_tickets-1 WHERE idblock = solded_ticket_id OR  idblock_pair = solded_ticket_id` ?

Comment: "**idblock_pair**" or "**idblock**" will never be the "**solded_ticket_id**" ...
The solded tickets are stored in another table, with the "**idblock**" and "**iduser**" as the foreign keys.
The problem is the database concurrency - many users disputing the same resource. If two people buy two tickets in the same time, it some situations it can result in a database inconsistency between the two cells.